# MVC Button Click performs action without redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, edit, buttonclick

I have a table where users are allowed to "tick" or "cross" out a row. Ticking a row changes the `status` value to "Approved" and crossing it changes it to "Disapproved". I'm currently using the Edit scaffold to perform it. How do I do this without having the user being redirected to the view. I just want the user to click it and the page refreshes, with the `status` value being updated.

I'm not sure what code to post here either since I don't know how to write it. If any part of my program is required, please let me know. I'll include it here. Thank you :>

Comment: You can use ajax to post the updated value to a controller method that saves it to the database, and in the success callback, update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add css classes to the 2 buttons "approve-btn" and "reject-btn".
2. Create javascript function to approve and reject and bind them to
   the 2 classes
3. Create 2 backend functions
4. Make ajax calls from the JS functions to your backend functions passing the id of the row item
5. In the "success:" of the ajax call manage the change of the status to show "approved" or "rejected"

To make ajax call you can use the following example (although there are tons of example on google). Since you're modifying data you should use POST call and since it is a POST call, you should add a RequestVerificationToken to prevent CSRF attacks.

```
function Approve(id){
    securityToken = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/YourControllerName/Approve/' + itemId,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "__RequestVerificationToken": securityToken
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'success')
                //use jQuery to show the approved message;
            else
                alert("something went wrong");                
        },
        error: function (request, err) {
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    });
}
```

The Token should be created in the View adding this line:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: How do i make ajax calls from the JS functions? :O sorry cause I just started MVC and I'm not familiar with Javascript